# I am making a login and sign up page for android but the sqlite database i use crashes on onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
package company.mystorage.com.mystorage;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mystorage.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "userlist";

public static final String COLUMN_1 ="Id";
private static final String COLUMN_2 = "username";
private static final String COLUMN_3 = "password";
SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        // database is created when constructor is called.
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        // to invoke onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods to create the tables
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_1 +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COLUMN_2 +" TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_3 +" TEXT)"
        );

    }

    public boolean insertData(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, username);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_3, password);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean searchPass(String user){
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select * from  " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_2 + " = " + "'" + user + "'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

This code will create a database and also contains the functions to search and add users to the database. I tried to debug the code and it showed that it crashed when the onCreate was called. I checked the onCreate but the query is being execute correctly.

Edited* I changed the this. for the db but it still crashed.

Comment: Please post stacktrace of your crash

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
>     this.db.execSQL(...)
> ```

You should be calling `execSQL()` on the `db` parameter and not `this.db` field that has not yet been initialized.

Comment: this makes the sense

Comment: I changed that but it still crashes. Is there any other problem?

Comment: Have a look at the stacktrace to learn where and why exactly your app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

This should help :

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
```

Please remove "this".

Also, in your method SearchPass(), if cursor has more count than it wont close the cursor and db object. It would be a better idea to handle that in Finally block.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` Method don't use `this` with `db.execSQL(..)`

Comment: Catching exceptions in `onCreate()` is almost always a bad idea. The method should not return normally if there was a problem creating database schema.

Comment: got it.Thanks for explaining (Y) @laalto